# How I can delete checkout step in my woocommerce store?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, checkout

I created a store by woocommerce and I want redirect customer to payment gateway or reduce wallet after click " add to cart". in other way I want to bypass checkout step.

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and then come back and edit your question to improve it.
Good questions are more likely to receive quick, better answers from the community.

Answer (score 1):

First, in the admin, go to **WooCommerce > Settings > Products** and disable both options under **Add to Cart Behavior**. The two options that you need to **disable** are:

- Redirect to the cart page after successful addition
- Enable AJAX add to cart buttons on archives

Next, in your theme's functions.php file, add the following code:

```
function so55387651_redirect_checkout_add_cart( $url ) {
    $url = get_permalink( get_option( 'woocommerce_checkout_page_id' ) );
    return $url;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'so55387651_redirect_checkout_add_cart' );
```

Comment: thank you for answering, but this function redirect customer to checkout page after click add to cart but I want redirect user to payment gateway or reduce wallet balance.